# getting a type Error when running file on node

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node and express, was trying to test some basics routes but getting a Type Error: Router.use() requires a middle ware function but got an object

This is what I have in app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const routes = require('./routes/api');
// set up express app
const app = express();

app.use('/api', routes);

//listen for request
app.listen(process.env.port || 4000, function(){
    console.log('now listening for requests');
});
```

and in my api.js:

```
const express = require('express');

//store router object to a vairable to enable us use routes on api.js
const router = express.Router();


router.get('/ninja', function(req, res){
    res.send('{type: "GET"}');
})

router.post('/ninja', function(req, res){
    res.send({type: "POST"});
})

//to update an api, where id is a parameter.
router.put('/ninja/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send({type: "PUT"});
})

//to delete an api
router.get('/ninja/:id', function(req, res){
    res.send({type: "DELETE"});
})

module.exports = router;
```

I have tried exporting `router` on each file, none worked.

Comment: That code is working for me.. if I do a get on http://localhost:4000/api/ninja I see a response of {type: "GET"}.

Comment: you know why mine is not working?

Comment: I can't really see it.. I'm running app.js and api.js is in a subfolder /routes. Running on node 10.5

Comment: I have the api.js in a folder called routes.... app.js and routes are in the same directory.

Comment: Are there any other files in the /routes directory?

Comment: nope just the api.js.... but could it be my node version or something?

Comment: Could be, my environment is: Node: 10.15.0, Express: 4.16.4.

Comment: okay... I'm using node: 11. 2. 0, same express version with you. maybe I'll download your version and try again. thanks

Comment: It's worth a go.. I suspect it is not the Node version, but you have to try!

Comment: It started working.... The code was okay. cant tell what the problem was. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Cool, just resetting your environment probably did the trick!